# how to get values from views.py and use it in html template?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-views

I'm making a Map where users can log in and assign default start and end points. I am very new to Django and html, now I am stuck on not knowing how to pass variable values into html.

this is my views.py

```
def maps(request):
    username = password = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:

                login(request, user)

                traffic_start = Auth.objects.get(user = user).traffic_start
                traffic_end = Auth.objects.get(user = user).traffic_end

    return render_to_response('maps.html')
```

and i'm trying to use the values in the html file here

```
function calcRoute(){
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){
      if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I tried looking for similar threads but I am still unable to figure it out, please help me, much appreciated!!

Comment: Many of you might think there's duplicates, but I just need more help, please be understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`render_to_response` has an optional argument that you can use just for that, it's called context. It has to be a dictionary.

```
render_to_response('maps.html', {'name': username})
```

You can use the value of username in your template with `{{ name }}`.
Check the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) for a sophisticated example project.

Comment: You linked to the development version of the tutorial. I would assume that the OP is using version 1.6, which differs in some significant ways.

Comment: I tried
 return render_to_response('maps.html', {'start': traffic_start, 'end': traffic_end})

and in html, I put
    <b>Start: </b>
    <input id="start" type = "textbox", value = {{start}}>

    <b>End: </b>
    <input id="end" type = "textbox", value = {{end}>

but it didn't work, how come?

Comment: In your HTML, try putting `value="{{ start }}"` and `value="{{ end }}"` in the input tags.

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass objects this way:

**Models.py**

```
class Profiles(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False)
```

Then reference this object in views.py and pass it to your template as @Tim Zimmermann mentioned

**Views.py**

```
profiles = Profiles.objects.all;
render_to_response('template.html', {'profiles': profiles })
```

You can then loop through them in your template:

**template.html**

```
{% for profile in profiles %}
      <p>{{ profile.first_name }}</p>
      <p>{{ profile.surname }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```